# shouldautorotate method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

App orientation has suddenly stopped working as intended. I have an app with a `tabBarController` working mainly in portrait mode. Some VC's override this to allow landscape. The deployment target is iPhone on `iOS` 9.0+.

The `shouldautorotate` method is no longer being called anywhere in the app, but `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called about 10 times (in the `tabbarController`) for each rotation (for different subVC's I guess).

This has all worked brilliantly before but if I check out an older branch where I know 100% that it worked, it still doesn't work. (I know this because I have a test build which works properly when I download it)

I've tried backtracking, cleaning, updating, reinstalling, re-downloading entire project, switching branches etc. but nothing works. I've gone through all warnings in the debugger output and tried a bunch of code solutions.

I'm wondering if it could be some sort of `plist` or project setting causing this. But, honestly, I hardly ever change project settings so I doubt it's that.

PS. This is not a duplicate of similarly titled questions. I've gone through them already. I'd be very grateful if anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Autorotation is the bane of my iOS existence. There was a perfectly good way of doing this pre-iOS 6, then there was a new way of doing this in iOS 6, then another way in iOS 7, and yet another way in iOS 8. According to the [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller?changes=_3&language=objc):

> As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method. When the interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view controller hierarchy.

Note that this method is called on the root view controller for the window, not the active/visible/whatever view controller. My root view controller dismisses any popovers then calls `setNeedsLayout` on its view. (I manually layout all my views so your requirements may be different.)

Comment: But shouldAutoRotate isn't marked as deprecated in the documentation. Why would it suddenly stop working? I guess I can magic up a solution with just supportedInterfaceOrientations, I'll just have to test and fix all the seven million VC's in my app.

Comment: What? The documentation doesn't match the behavior of iOS?? I'm shocked! :-) The fact of the matter is that all the rotation-related methods in `UIViewController` are deprecated as of iOS 8.